# Copy array from certain position to another array in c

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, memmove

I have array A and i want to copy this array from position x till y to another array in C language. Please help in creating it in c.

Using memcpy copies array from beginning only. I want to copy from particular position to another position.

Comment: `memcpy(dest,&array[42],42)` ?

Comment: Search for, and read about, pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `memcpy(another, A + x, sizeof(*A)*(y-x));//It does not include y`

Answer (score 6):

```
int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int b[5];

memcpy( b, a + 5, 5 * sizeof( int ) );
```

Also you can do this using an ordinary for loop

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) b[i] = a[i+5];
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are copying into another array, you can use `memcpy()`:

```
memcpy(another_array, array + x, (y - x) * sizeof(*array));
```

If you were copying into the same array, you should use `memmove()` instead.

```
memmove(array + z, array + x, (y - x) * sizeof(*array));
```

For each, the first parameter denotes the destination, and the functions assume the destination has enough space to accept the complete copy.

Answer (score 3):

`memcpy` only copies from the beginning of an array if that's what address you pass it. The name of an array `a` is synonymous with the address of the first element `&a[0]`, so if you do `memcpy(dest, src, size)`, then the copy will be from the start of the array `src`.

Pointer arithmetic can be used to start the copy from a point further along in your array. For example, to copy 10 elements starting from element 2 in array `src`, you can do this:

```
size_t size = 10 * sizeof (int);
int * dest = malloc(size);
memcpy(dest, src + 2, size);  // or equivalently, &src[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=x, j=0; i<=y; i++, j++)
   AnotherArray[j]= A[i];
```

Comment: That's a nice simple solution but it's linear time where using memcpy would be constant time.

Comment: I know memcpy is faster then simple loop, But memcpy is not constant time for sure..

Answer (score 0):

## Copy arrays with `memcpy`

```c
void * memcpy (void * destination, void * source, size_t size)
```

The `memcpy` function copies an certain amount of bytes from a source memory location and writes them to a destinaction location. [(Documentation)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)

### Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int some_array[] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    
    int memory_amount = sizeof(some_array);
    int item_count = memory_amount / sizeof(some_array[0]);
    int *pointer = malloc(memory_amount);
    memcpy(pointer, &some_array, memory_amount);

    while (item_count--)
        printf("%d=%d\n", item_count, *(pointer + item_count));

    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
$ ./a.out 
4=14
3=13
2=12
1=11
0=10
```